# Cannot implement property using derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, serialization, interface, derived-class

```
public interface IBase
{
    int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IDerivedA : IBase
{
    int Name { get; set; }
    int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public interface IDerivedB : IBase
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<IDerivedA> DerivedBs { get; set; }
}
```

And here is an implementation for a class which will be serialized, but I'm getting compilation error when I try to use **DerivedASerialize** class which is a derived class from **IDerivedA** interface

```
[MessagePack.Union(0, typeof(DerivedASerialize))]
[MessagePack.Union(1, typeof(DerivedBSerialize))]
[MessagePack.MessagePackObject(true)]
public class BaseSerialize : IBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsNull { get;set; }
}

[MessagePack.MessagePackObject(true)]
public class DerivedASerialize : BaseSerialize, IDerivedA
{
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

[MessagePack.MessagePackObject(true)]
public class DerivedBSerialize : BaseSerialize, IDerivedB
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DerivedASerialize> DerivedBs { get; set; }
}
```

Is there any work around? as I can only serialize classes.

And I would like to have another class which also derive from the same interface and have different properties

Using neuec's MessagePack.

Edit: Add serialization logic to classes.

Comment: Property 'DerivedBs' cannot implement property from interface 'IDerivedB'. Type should be 'IDerivedA'

Comment: How are you serializing the class?
Show us that code as well

Comment: See update @bashrc

Answer (score 1):

If you require two different "Name" fields you can use explicit interface implementation:

```
public class DerivedBSerialize : BaseSerialize, IDerivedB
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DerivedASerialize> DerivedBs { get; set; }
    string IDerivedB.Name { get; set; }
    IEnumerable<IDerivedA> IDerivedB.DerivedBs { get; set; }
}
```

If you require just a single "Name" field - you can raise it to "IBase", or create another interface -

```
interface INameable { string Name {get; set;} }
```

Comment: I have tried that, but when I serialize the class I will get an exception as I cannot serialize an interface, tho I can add it an ignore attribute, but with more classes it will become to look cluttered..

Comment: I've edited my answer - I think adding another one or two interfaces may resolve your issue, let me know if that helps